# How to make php redirect all sublinks to my index page?

Tags: php

how to make php or htaccess or something like that : if the user try to enter any other link accept this link : localhost/test/index.php so my website redirect him automatically to my index.php link : localhost/test/index.php

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that I usually use doesn't require you to specify the directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)? index.php?uri=$1 [QSA]
```

Then you can use `$_GET['uri']` to see what page the user requested. Be careful, as this will make all CSS and images and etc also go to your `index.php`.

If you want to exclude any directories from this (say perhaps `./assets/`), then you can put another `.htaccess` file inside those directories:

```
RewriteEngine off
```

Answer (score 0):

this, in .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ localhost/test/index.php [L]
```

Comment: not working brother i put my .htaccess in the same directery of my index.php